# Sql CMD Command with parameters

Tags: c#, sql, sqlcmd

I got this code from Stackoverflow to insert data in table.
But I wonder what it actually doing can someone please explain me this, What cmd.Parameters.add method does?
2: Why data conversion required?
3: What is @BSal here ?

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@BSal", SqlDbType.Decimal).Value = Convert.ToDecimal(txtBSal.Text);
                    cmd.Connection = Connection.con;
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: LOL well if you got the code from `SO` then why not step thru the code and see for yourself what it's doing.. also if you are not familiar with SQL Command Parameters then MSDN is a great place to start.. come on now show some more effort

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameterCollection.Add(v=vs.110).aspx Simple search will take you here.

Comment: It's a [parameterized](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb738521%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) query. They help make them reusable so you can execute the same query with different requirements. For example, if I have a database with 1,000 people, I shouldn't write 1,000 queries with different names when I can write one query and change the name required.

Answer (score 1):

`@BSal` is the name of a SQL parameter in your stored procedure or SQL statement.

`cmd.Parameters.Add` fills in a SQL parameter's values. The convert to Decimal is required because the type of the parameter is `SqlDbType.Decimal` and currently `txtBSal` is a text box, so you must convert the string to a decimal before it can be used.